# Confusing pointer declaration

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm reading appendix A of Accelerated C++. There the authors show an example of a declaration which looks like this:

```
const char * const * const * cp;
```

They say const char is the specifier and * const * const * cp is the declarator. I'm confused about the purpose of the extra const and *s. Is this a declaration of a const pointer to a const char?

Comment: It's a declaration of a "pointer to const pointer to const pointer to const char", I believe. And this is why C++.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's the declaration of

- a pointer
- to a const pointer
- to a const pointer
- to `const char`

Thus you may change `cp`, but you may not change any of

```
*cp
**cp
***cp
```

Comment: And why would anyone ever want to do this?

Comment: @crush Sadism? I have never used triple pointers yet, I don't know when you would need them.

Comment: It is exceedingly rare that I find an instance where a double pointer is useful.

Comment: @crush Rare, but that happens, consider for example `long int strtol(const char *nptr, char **endptr, int base);` and friends.

Comment: Yeah, so I guess a triple pointer might be used in conjunction with an array of strings where you are pointing to a specific character of a specific string in that array? There are certainly better ways to handle this that take advantage of C++

Comment: Obligatory [three star programmer](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer) reference.

Answer (score 4):

As we can see from [cdecl](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=const%20char%20%2a%20const%20%2a%20const%20%2a%20cp;), `cp` is a `pointer` to `const pointer` to `const pointer` to `const char`.

You can see this by breaking it down right-to-left:

```
const char * const * const * cp;
                             cp is
                           a pointer
                   to const pointer
           to const pointer
to const char
```

Also, the standard (§ 8) says that:

> The speciﬁers indicate the type, storage class or other properties
>   of the entities being declared. The declarators specify the names
>   of these entities and (optionally) modify the type of the speciﬁers
>   with operators such as * (pointer to) and () (function returning).

Answer (score 1):

From [cdecl.org](http://www.cdecl.org):

> declare cp as pointer to const pointer to const pointer to const char

Answer (score 1):

This is the same as char * * * cp except that all the pointers are const, except one. Since char***cp is a pointer to a pointer to a pointer your example is the same but it is a pointer to a const pointer to a const pointer

Comment: Formatting-cat got your tongue? ;)

Comment: Not anymore, the stars made some of the text bold

Comment: "all the pointers are const" - no, two pointers are const, one pointers is non-const

Comment: @kotlomoy fixed it but notice that I had it correct in the second half previously